# How do I know if a string contains a character that is also in my list?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to know if my_string contains a character that is also in my_list

```
my_list = ['d', 'n', 'q', 't']
my_string = 'Hello World'
```

I tried this but It's too long

```
my_list = ['d', 'n', 'q', 't']
my_string = 'Hello World'

if 'd' in my_string or 'n' in my_string or 'q' in my_string or 't' in my_string:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `set.intersection`:

```py
my_list = ["d", "n", "q", "t"]
my_string = "Hello World"

if set(my_string).intersection(my_list):  # this will return `{'d'}` which evaluates to True
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Please try to search for existing duplicates before answering. This one was not hard to find; I tried `[python] string contains any` in the site search and scrolled through the descriptions a little.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function, along with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), and then convert the result to a list in order to find if any of the characters in list, are part of the string:

```
my_list = ['d', 'n', 'q', 't']
my_string = 'Hello World'

if any(map(lambda ch: ch in my_string, my_list)):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: You don't really need the `list()` - `any()` can consume the iterator produced by `map()`. In fact, `list()` defeats the short circuiting of `any()`.

Comment: @Mark let me fix that.